Send controller signal to a console from a pc
Hello would it be possible to plug a controller to a pc then send the controller signal to the console as if the controller was directly plugged to the console.
This would be usefull to edit the signal like creating macros and a more in depth controller customisation (add negative deadzone custom keybinds...) or any kind of things like this.
I tryed first of all to basicly plug to the pc then to the console i knew it would not work but still i tryed then i searched for software doing this and didn't found anything
